# Tangent not being vertical near a point $p$ of a level curve $\mathcal{C}$ $\implies$ all vertical lines near $p$ intersect $C$ at a unique point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry

This is from the "proof" of the theorem 1.5.1 from *Elementary Differential Geometry* by Andrew Pressley (pp. 23).

The hypothesis is that: Let $f(x, y)$ be a smooth function of two variables, and assume that the partial derivatives of $f$ w.r.t. x and y are non-zero at every point of the level curve $\mathcal{C} = \{(x, y) \in \mathrm{R}^2 \mid f(x, y) = 0\}$. Then, if $\mathbb{p}$ is a point of $\mathcal{C}$, with $\mathbb{p} = (x_0, y_0)$, there is a regular parametrized curve $\gamma(t)$, defined on an open interval containing $0$, such that $\gamma(0) = \mathbb{p}$, and $\gamma(t) \in \mathcal{C}, \forall t$.

In the "proof", the author states that:

> The hypothesis tells us that the vector $\mathbb{n} = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$ is non-zero at every point of $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose, for example that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \neq 0$ at $\mathbb{p}$. Then, $\mathbb{n}$ is not parallel to the x-axis at $\mathbb{p}$, so the tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ at $\mathbb{p}$ is not parallel to the y-axis.
> **This implies that the vertical lines $x$ = constant near $x = x_0$ all intersect $\mathcal{C}$ in a unique point $(x_0, y_0)$ near $\mathbb{p}$.**

My question is that why does the implication happen? Namely, how do you argue mathematically that tangent not being vertical at a point $\mathbb{p}$ of a curve implies that all vertical lines near $\mathbb{p}$ intersect the curve at a unique point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is essentially the statement of the implicit function theorem. The implicit function theorem in this scenario tells us that the equation $f(x, y) = 0$ defines $y = g(x)$ for $x$ near $x_0$ with $g(x_0) = y_0$ and $g$ a $C^\infty$ (i.e. smooth) map.

The implicit function theorem is an easy consequence of the inverse function theorem. The inverse function theorem is a (not as easy) consequence of the contraction mapping theorem.